# MS Excel: Set value X if a certain value Y is already set for a group of records

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of message records identified that belong to a conversation. For a conversation id, there are multiple message ids. Based on duration between each exchange within a conversation, the values in columns 'SLA Upfront' and 'SLA Ongoing' will be set. The condition being:

- For a message within a conversation, SLA Upfront is set if duration > 3 mins
- Once 'SLA Upfront is set, from then on, withing the same conversation if duration of exchange > 1 min, SLA Ongoing' flag should be set
- My question is, how do I set the 'ongoing flag' once an 'upfront flag' is set?

Here's the snapshot:

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is... probably not the most elegant, but it'll work. I assume your data starts in column A.

First of all, I created a new column called "uf2", which has a value of 1 when a prior message in the conversation id was an upfront breach, and otherwise has a value of 0.

Here's an image of what it would look like...

[image]

Green cell formula (F2): `=IF(AND(C2="agent", E2>3), 1, 0)`

Purple cell formula (G2): `=SUMIF(A2:$A$2, A2, F2:$F$2)-F2`

Blue cell formula (H2): `=IF(AND(G2>=1, C2="agent", E2>1), "SLA ONGOING BREACH", "")`

Fill all these formulas down.

Of course, this all assumes the data is sorted by conversation id and message id as it was in your original image.